# how to access a matrix and increase specific column?

Tags: python

For example, I have this matrix, and I need to access the second column and increase it by 2:

```
 m = [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what problem did you face with your attempt?

Comment: You're probably looking for a library like [NumPy](https://numpy.org/install/#python-and-numpy-installation-guide).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that just by accessing the 2nd column and incrementing the value. You can do that by doing this : `m[:, 1] = m[:, 1] + 2`

It means that you are ignoring all the rows and specifying the columns. Here, 1 refers to the 2nd column.

You can do this by using numpy library which allows you to easily do such thing.

Import numpy as `import numpy as np`

Convert the 2d list into numpy array

```
m = np.array([
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.]
])
```

Now apply the conditioning

```
m[:, 1] = m[:, 1] + 2
```

Print the output.

```
print("M: ", m)
```

Combined Code:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
 [0., 0., 0., 0.]
 ])

m[:, 1] = m[:, 1] + 2
print("M: ", m)
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to increase the second element of each row by 2. You could achieve this by a for loop.

```
for row in m:
    row[1] += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the matrix into a numpy array. Just in case you're looking at exploiting the optimisations that this library offers

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([
    [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
    [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
    [0., 0., 0., 0.], 
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]
])

m[:, 1] += 1
```